# Remove "Item x" from Eclipse Graphical Editor preview of ListView

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have created a custom xml file that contains some elements that make up the rows in a ListView. I've set the preview of the ListView to be this xml file. I can't figure out how to get rid of the default "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" ... however.

Does anyone have an idea on what could be causing this?

Here's the code as well as a screenshot:

**my_custom_list.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">


     <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
         <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/my_custom_list_row -->
     </ListView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**my_custom_list_row.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
         />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text="Senders Name"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Subject"

            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla viverra mattis nulla nec sollicitudin." />

      </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot of list]

Comment: +1 for you. ADT eclipse IS the form designer of choice for Android so we really need custom listviews previews working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not seem possible or this is a bug in the ADT plugin that I keep running into. I get by by just previewing the row to make sure it looks ok. If you need to render UI images you can use something like [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) and import [Android Stencils](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Downloads/Stencils.aspx) to it.